# if one field is filled other field is required in xml?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, odoo

```
<field name="warranty_from" attrs = "{'readonly': [('state','in',['approved'])]}"/>
<field name="expiry_date" attrs = "{'readonly': [('state','in',['approved'])]}"/>
```

How to write a condition in xml if one (warranty_from) field is filled then expiry_date should not be empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your xml could be as following:

```xml
<field name="warranty_from" attrs = "{'readonly': [('state','in',['approved'])]}"/>
<field name="expiry_date" attrs = "{'required': [('warranty_from','!=', False)]}"/>
```